# How to stop Maven from downloading all historical versions of aws-java-sdk?

Tags: maven

I am using Maven to download `aws-java-sdk` dependency for version `1.11.23`, though in Maven repository I find all historical versions till most recent ones; i.e. `aws-java-sdk-sqs` downloaded versions (`1.9.0` to `1.11.642`) any idea why is that and how can I limit to only the version specified for `aws-java-sdk` artifact?

Comment: same thing is happening to me

Answer (score 2):

This "dependency loop" is a problem with some older versions of `aws-lambda-java-events`, which is probably a dependency of your dependency.

Try updating or your dependencies to the latest, or overriding `aws-lambda-java-events` to at least 2.2.7:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, After specifying the BOM of AWS SDK in the dependencyManagement section & the version I would like to use, The historical downloads were stopped. Below are my dependencies.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I was getting similar issues despite not depending directly on `aws-java-sdk`. Adding the BOM pinned the underlying dependency and stopped it downloading all versions of the library. Massively reduced my build times!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because this is also what the documentation advises doing.

Answer (score -2):

I created a project (with Maven 3.5.4) with just:

```xml
<project ... >
    ....
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.23</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

All of `~/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/*` (as declared in [`aws-java-sdk`s POM](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.11.23/jar)) contain just the sub-directory `/1.11.23`.

**UPDATE**

To exclude dependencies of your dependencies see [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism, Transitive Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies):

> - *Excluded dependencies* - If project X depends on project Y, and project Y depends on project Z, the owner of project X can explicitly exclude project Z as a dependency, using the "exclusion" element.

Comment: aws-java-sdk itself only contains 1.11.23, but some packages as "aws-java-sdk-sqs" contains all historical versions start from 1.9.0 till 1.11.642?!

Comment: how to exclude sub-package "org.xml.sax" of maven jar below? <dependency>
   <groupId>saxon</groupId>
   <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
   <version>6.5.2</version>
   </dependency>

Comment: @Telebh See **Dependency Management** on that very same page: `<dependency>...<exclusions><exclusion>...` and [POM Reference, Exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Exclusions).

Comment: It worked after adding <exclusion> for the duplicated jars.